# Is there a way to list all files tracked by remote repositories?

Tags: git

I know that I can list the files tracked by a certain branch using `git ls-tree -r <branch> --name-only` and this gives me exactly what I was looking for. However when I try to do this with a remote-only branch i get the error: `sh: origin/master: No such file or directory`. So is there a way I can list files in a remote branch without pulling that branch?

Comment: It should work with remote branches as well... I just checked and it works. I think you should paste the command you are running and the error message in the question

Comment: The error was printed from a script I ran to run the command on all branches in a repo and apparently one of the commands got populated with `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master` which obviously messed up the command. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth mentioning first that this is not the set of files *tracked by a branch* or *tracked by a (Git) repository* as these phrases aren't really well-defined.  The result of `git ls-files -r` on a commit is the *set of files in that commit*.

The word *tracked* in Git is rather overloaded, but when we talk about a *tracked file* vs an *untracked file* in Git, what we mean is *a file that is, or is not, in the index right now*.

The set of files that *will be* in Git's index, if you use `git checkout` or `git switch` to extract some particular commit, is normally<sup>1</sup> the set of files that is in that commit.  So in that sense, you can call those "tracked" files, but if you do, you're setting yourself up for confusion.  The tracked files are those that are in Git's index *right now*.  You can *change* that set any time you like:

```
git add F
```

will copy the work-tree copy of file `F` into Git's index.<sup>2</sup>  If it was not there before—was untracked—well, now it is, so now it's tracked.  Or:

```
git rm --cached F
```

will *remove* the index copy of file F.  If it was there before, it's not now; now file `F` is untracked.  It doesn't matter if file `F` is in, or not in, some other commit, unless and until you check out that commit.

Whenever you make a new commit, Git makes that new commit using the files that are in the index at that time.  Even the commands `git commit -a`, `git commit --include files`, and `git commit --only files` work with the index, although these make use of extra, temporary index files as well so as to make the updates easy to roll back in case of failures.  (This makes describing their exact action, especially in the presence of Git hooks, particularly tricky.)

Meanwhile, you can inspect any commit that you have, using `git ls-files -r` on it; you just have to use a name that Git can turn into the correct commit hash ID.  [As you noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256367/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-files-tracked-by-remote-repositories#comment111856725_63256367), you were using two names instead of one name.

---

<sup>1</sup>The word *normally* is here because you can play various tricks with Git's index, or use an alternate index, by setting the environment variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE`.  Also, Git will sometimes allow you to carry index and/or work-tree changes across commit and/or branch switching operations.  For the gory details, see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).

<sup>2</sup>If you've set the `--assume-unchanged` or `--skip-worktree` bits on a file that is currently in the index, `git add` won't update the index from the work-tree.  You can use `GIT_INDEX_FILE` as in footnote 1 as well.